# Regex extract thrid number

Tags: r, regex

I have some strings and I am trying to extract the third number that appears in it (in R).
This is an example string, all of them have the same pattern:

```
string = "Speaks 2 times (1%) for a total of 34 words (1%)."
```

I have been able to get the first number with `str_extract(string, "[0-9]+")`
But I have no idea on how to take only the third (the number of words).
Any help would be gratly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `str_locate` to find the location of the substring and extract

```
library(stringr)
ind <- str_locate_all(string, "\\d+")[[1]][3,]
str_sub(string, ind[1], ind[2])
[1] "34"
```

---

Or using `base R` with `strsplit`

```
setdiff(strsplit(string, "\\D+")[[1]], "")[3]
[1] "34"
```

#### data

```
string <-  "Speaks 2 times (1%) for a total of 34 words (1%)."
```

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to target the number before the text `words`:

```r
string <- "Speaks 2 times (1%) for a total of 34 words (1%)."
num <- sub("^.*\\b(\\d+) words\\b.*", "\\1", string)
num

[1] "34"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract all matches and grab the 3rd item:

```r
library(stringr)
string = "Speaks 2 times (1%) for a total of 34 words (1%)."
unlist(str_extract_all(string, "[0-9]+"))[3]
## => [1] "34"
```

Also, you can use `sub`:

```r
sub("^(?:\\D+\\d+){2}\\D+(\\d+).*", "\\1", string)
## => [1] "34"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/fHLjlV). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\D+\d+){2}` - two occurrences of any one or more non-digit chars and then one or more digits (**note**: replace `{2}` with `{3}` to extract the fourth number, or remove it to get the second number, adjust as you see fit)
- `\D+` - zero or more non-digit chars
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`\1`): one or more digits
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an other way:
First match all numbers then subset vector on position 3:

```
sapply(regmatches(string, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", string)), function(x) x[3])
```

```
[1] "34"
```